# Android: Como cargar miniatura de audio de External Storage?

Tags: android, kotlin

estoy tratando de cargar miniaturas de audio con el siguiente código, pero ThumbnailUtils.createAudioThumbnail me devuelve nulo, ¿alguien puede ayudarme?

```
       var bitmap by remember { mutableStateOf<Bitmap?>(null)}
            val file: File = File("/storage/emulated/0/snaptube/download/SnapTube Audio/PA_ ROMPERLA 
       - Bad Bunny x Don Omar _  Las Que No(MP3_128K).mp3")
            var bmap: Bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createAudioThumbnail(
                    file, Size(100, 100), null
            )
            Log.e(TAG, "$bmap")
            Glide.with(AmbientContext.current).asBitmap()
                .load(R.drawable.image)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.image)
                .error(R.drawable.image)
                .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    override fun onResourceReady(
                            resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                    ) {
                        bitmap = resource
                    }

                    override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }
                })
            if(bitmap != null){
                Image(bitmap!!.asImageBitmap())
            }
```

Comment: Te recomiendo traducir el título, ya que las preguntas en otro idioma suelen ser borradas o cerradas.

Comment: Regularmente las miniaturas son de una imagen no de un audio, si deseas obtener la minuatura del album de la canciòn mp3 es una pregunta algo amplia.

Comment: @Jorgesys si sabes como sacar la del album dame una respuesta!!